Error with vagrant (and nokogiri) on fedora 40
On a freshly installed Fedora 40 distribution, I want to use vagrant but I got an error (seems to be a problem with nokogiri).
I think vagrant is not packaged like it could be or maybe a dependance is not satisfied.
Ignoring bcrypt_pbkdf-1.1.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt_pbkdf --version 1.1.0
Ignoring bigdecimal-3.1.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 3.1.5
Ignoring debug-1.9.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug --version 1.9.1
Ignoring ed25519-1.3.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ed25519 --version 1.3.0
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring io-console-0.7.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine io-console --version 0.7.1
Ignoring json-2.7.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.7.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.16.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.16.5
Ignoring psych-5.1.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine psych --version 5.1.2
Ignoring racc-1.7.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.7.3
Ignoring ruby-libvirt-0.7.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ruby-libvirt --version 0.7.1
Ignoring psych-5.1.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine psych --version 5.1.2
<internal:/home/nico/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
    from <internal:/home/nico/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.16.5/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:31:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.16.5/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
...

I tried to reinstall nokogiri manually with :
gem install nokogiri
But I got the same issue.

I fixed it installing Vagrant with Hashicorp's package repository.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/downloads
I think the Vagrant package from Fedora is broken.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The install from the official package avoids many issues with the ruby dependency hell, for Fedora or other linux distributions.
